# How to get session duration in Standard SQL (BigQuery)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following table (table name is chats) and I would like to get the session duration for each contact and also the average session duration overall.

| Owner | timestamp | inbound_timestamp | outbound_timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21766666666 | 2021-03-09T06:55:06 | 2021-03-09T06:55:04 | 2021-03-09T06:55:06 |
| 21766666666 | 2021-03-09T12:36:08 | 2021-03-09T12:36:05 | 2021-03-09T12:36:08 |
| 21766666666 | 2021-03-09T17:54:09 | 2021-03-09T17:54:06 | 2021-03-09T17:54:09 |
| 21722222222 | 2021-04-16T12:41:34 | 2021-04-16T12:41:33 | 2021-04-16T12:41:34 |
| 21722222222 | 2021-04-16T12:42:48 | 2021-04-16T12:42:33 | 2021-04-16T12:42:48 |
| 21722222222 | 2021-04-16T12:43:39 | 2021-04-16T12:43:30 | 2021-04-16T12:43:39 |

**Context:**

The application that owns this records is a bot. From row one, contact 21766666666 sends a message to the bot at inbound_timestamp(2021-03-09T06:55:04), the bot replies at outbound_timestamp (2021-03-09T06:55:06) and the outboump is saved as timestamp.
Same user replies again second row and third row.
Rows 4,5 and 6 are from a different user.

I'd like to be able to have a table which shows each user's average session time per day **AND** the total average session time per day. **By session time I mean how long each user spent on the app (first inbound_timestamp - last outbound_timestamp)**

Is this possible from the data I have.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to be able to have a table which shows each user's average session time per day AND the total average session time per day

Consider below approach

```
select *, 
  avg(session_duration) over all_users_day as  average_session_duration
from (
  select distinct owner, day, 
    timestamp_diff(max(ts) over user_day, min(ts) over user_day, minute) as session_duration,
  from (
    select owner, ts, date(ts) day
    from (
      select owner, 
        min(inbound_timestamp) inbound_timestamp, 
        max(outbound_timestamp) outbound_timestamp
      from data
      group by owner
    ), 
    unnest(generate_timestamp_array(inbound_timestamp, outbound_timestamp, interval 1 minute)) ts
  )
  window 
    user_day as (partition by owner, day)
)
window all_users_day as (partition by day)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]